# ループ再生されるGIF画像の作り方

Tags: java

下記が現在のソースです

```
package creategif;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * メインクラスです.
 * @author udon
 */
public class CreateGif {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "anime.gif");
        try {
            //書き込みストリームの作成
            Iterator<ImageWriter> it = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif");
            ImageWriter writer = it.hasNext() ? it.next() : null;
            ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(file);
            if(writer == null) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
            writer.setOutput(stream);
            writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);
            //画像の作成
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(128, 128, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(16, 16, 8, 8);
            final Color FG = Color.WHITE;
            final Color BG = Color.BLACK;
            //50回□を動かすアニメーション
            for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
                Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
                //背景を塗りつぶす
                g.setColor(BG);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
                //□を描画
                g.setColor(FG);
                g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                //動かす
                rect.x += 2;
                //フレームの追加
                writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(image, null, null), null);
            }
            writer.endWriteSequence();
            stream.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "失敗しました\n" + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

また、下記の環境でアニメーション再生されることも確認済みです

```
Chrome 48.0.2564.116 m
IE 11.0.9600.18205
```

ただこれはアニメーションを一通り再生するとそのまま停止してしまうのですが、
これを無限にループ再生させる方法はありますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Create animated GIF using imageio | Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1264385)を参考にして、以下のような`IIOMetadata`を書き込むようにすると、ループ可能になるようです。

```
//Create animated GIF using imageio | Oracle Community
//https://community.oracle.com/thread/1264385
ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(image), iwp);
String metaFormat = metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName();
Node root = metadata.getAsTree(metaFormat);
IIOMetadataNode aes = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtensions");
IIOMetadataNode ae = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");
ae.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
ae.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");
byte[] uo = {
  //last two bytes is an unsigned short (little endian) that
  //indicates the the number of times to loop.
  //0 means loop forever.
  0x1, 0x0, 0x0
};
ae.setUserObject(uo);
aes.appendChild(ae);
root.appendChild(aes);
metadata.setFromTree(metaFormat, root);

//...
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  //...
  //フレームの追加
  writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(image, null, metadata), null);
  metadata = null; //先頭フレームだけで良い？
```

[GIFメタデータ形式の仕様](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/gif_metadata.html)を見ればもっと詳しい仕様が書いてあるかもと思ったのですが、ここではアニメーションのループは良く分からないですね...。

**CreateGif2.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.metadata.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CreateGif2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "anime.gif");
    try {
      //書き込みストリームの作成
      Iterator<ImageWriter> it = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif");
      ImageWriter writer = it.hasNext() ? it.next() : null;
      ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(file);
      if (writer == null) {
        throw new IOException();
      }
      writer.setOutput(stream);
      writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);
      //画像の作成
      BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(128, 128, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

      //Create animated GIF using imageio | Oracle Community
      //https://community.oracle.com/thread/1264385
      ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
      IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(image), iwp);
      String metaFormat = metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName();
      Node root = metadata.getAsTree(metaFormat);
      IIOMetadataNode aes = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtensions");
      IIOMetadataNode ae = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");
      ae.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
      ae.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");
      byte[] uo = {
        //last two bytes is an unsigned short (little endian) that
        //indicates the the number of times to loop.
        //0 means loop forever.
        0x1, 0x0, 0x0
      };
      ae.setUserObject(uo);
      aes.appendChild(ae);
      root.appendChild(aes);
      metadata.setFromTree(metaFormat, root);

      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(16, 16, 8, 8);
      final Color FG = Color.WHITE;
      final Color BG = Color.BLACK;
      //50回□を動かすアニメーション
      for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
        //背景を塗りつぶす
        g.setColor(BG);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
        //□を描画
        g.setColor(FG);
        g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        g.dispose();

        //動かす
        rect.x += 2;

        //フレームの追加
        writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(image, null, metadata), null);
        metadata = null; //先頭フレームだけで良い？
      }
      writer.endWriteSequence();
      stream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "失敗しました\n" + ioe.getMessage());
      });
    }
  }
}
```

- 追記: ループは Netscape による拡張らしいです

  - [JDK-6738539 Support GIF Netscape Loop Extension in javax.imageio.ImageWriter - Java Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6738539)
  - [GIFフォーマットの詳細](http://www.tohoho-web.com/wwwgif.htm)

    > Application Extension は Netscape によって拡張された Loop Control として使用され、Application Identifier には "NETSCAPE"、Application Authentication Code には "2.0" の文字が格納される。Application Data として1バイトの 0x01 および2バイトのループ回数(0～65535)が、例えばループ回数が5回の場合は 0x01 0x05 0x00 の3バイトが格納される。